# Passing Data from one HTML to another HTML both using the same angular controller onClick

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am retrieving all the data and storing it in a variable "storedata", displaying it in the HTML View "A" which is associated with an angular Controller, I am making use of thymeleaf template and however on click of the ID i want to display the contents in another HTML View "B" for which i want to make use of the variable "storedata" which already has the data. So I tried linking HTML View "B" with the same angular Controller thinking that I could access it directly, however i couldn't. your suggestion would be valuable. all the files are pasted below.

HTML "A"

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="storedata in storeDataModel">
       <a  class="clickableRow" title="Click to get User details" onclick="window.open('B.html')" >{{storedata.ID}}
    </a>
</div>
```

HTML "B"

```
<div ng-controller="angularController">
<a> HELLO WORLD..!! {{storedata.ID}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably use a service for something like this, since changing the view will initialize a new instance of the controller without the `storedata` variable

Comment: oh okay, didn't know that it would create a new instance of angular controller, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load another view without bootstrapping it. By calling window. open, you are only loading a html file that has nothing to do with the angular application you are working with. 
For more info, take a look at [angular bootstrapping.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Another approach would be to use [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io). I suggest the latter one.

For example look at below code:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // State definition
    $stateProvider
      .state('homeState', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/home',
        template: '<div> {{ title }} ' +
          '<div ui-view><div>' +
          '</div>',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      })
      .state('homeState.childStateA', {
        url: '/stateA',
        template: '<div> {{ data }} </div>' +
          '<button data-ng-click="$state.go(\'homeState.childStateB\')"> Click Me To GoTo StateB </button>',
        controller: 'StateAController'
      })
      .state('homeState.childStateB', {
        url: '/stateB',
        template: '<div> {{ data }} </div>' +
          '<button data-ng-click="$state.go(\'homeState.childStateA\')"> Click Me To GoTo StateA </button>',
        controller: 'StateBController'
      });

    // Default to stateA
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/stateA');
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  })
  .controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
    // homeState data
    $scope.title = 'State example';
  })
  .controller('StateAController', function($scope) {
    // StateA data
    $scope.data = 'Hi State A';
  })
  .controller('StateBController', function($scope) {
    // StateB data
    $scope.data = 'Hi State B';
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```